Need help with labeling in the BarLegend and Contours
I am plotting the overlay of DensityPlot and ContourPlot, but I am facing issues with formatting the labels for both.
I have the following code:
MaxV=Abs[NMaximize[{10^8/(x^2+y^2),0.01<=x<=1,1<=y<=5},{x,y}][[1]]];
MinV=NMinimize[{10^8/(x^2+y^2),0.01<=x<=1,1<=y<=5},{x,y}][[1]];

f[x_]:=x/. {NumberForm[y_,{w_,z_}]:>ScientificForm[y,2]};

Dplot=DensityPlot[10^8/(x^2+y^2),{x,0.01,1},{y,1,5},PlotRange->All,Frame->{True,True,True,True},
FrameLabel->{Style["\[Zeta]",20,Bold, Black],Style["\[Kappa]",20,Bold, Black]},
FrameTicksStyle->{{Directive[Black,20],Directive[FontOpacity->0,FontSize->0]},{Directive[Black,20],Directive[FontOpacity->0,FontSize->0]}},
PlotLegends->BarLegend[{Automatic,{MinV,MaxV}} ,40,LegendMarkerSize->{10,250},LabelStyle->{FontSize->20,Black},LegendLabel->"Value",LegendFunction->f]];

Cplot=ContourPlot[10^8/(x^2+y^2),{x,0.01,1},{y,1,5},ContourShading->None,
ContourLabels->(Style[Text[#3,{#1,#2},Background->RGBColor[255/255,255/255,255/255,0.5]],14,RGBColor[0.1,0.2,0.2]]&),
ContourStyle->{Dashed},Contours->5 10^5*Flatten[{1,Range[10,50,10]}],BaseStyle->18];

Show[Dplot,Cplot]

As a result, I obtain the output shown below (left), which is not exactly what I want,  and tried to draw on the right side. Specifically, I would like to achieve the following: 1) Label the contours in engineering notation, such as 1e6, and 2) Relabel the BarLegend so that instead of random equidistant numbers 1.2x10^7, 2.3x10^7, ..., I have a given set of integer numbers (or any other on desire) placed appropriately on the bar (see the image below), with their common multiplier of x10^7 displayed at the bottom.

Could the community please provide hints to achieve the output shown in the right image?

Have you considered changing the values of your data instead, e.g. by dividing it by 10^7? That may be much more straightforward.

@MarcoB thank you for the response. Yes you right, this is shotest way. Nonetheless I prefer to know and understand mechanics of what I am using, Below is my way to solve the issue I posted.

This is what I found acceptable to myself, still plays with the ColorSchemes, but the questions I asked are solved (imho)
MaxV=Abs[NMaximize[{10^8/(x^2+y^2),0.01<=x<=1,1<=y<=5},{x,y}][[1]]];
MinV=NMinimize[{10^8/(x^2+y^2),0.01<=x<=1,1<=y<=5},{x,y}][[1]];
ChosenTicksBAR=N[{5 10^6,10 10^6,15 10^6,20 10^6,25 10^6,47 10^6,80 10^6}];
ForTicks=Transpose@{ChosenTicksBAR,N[ChosenTicksBAR/10^6]};
ChosenTicksC={5 10^6,10 10^6,15 10^6,20 10^6,25 10^6};


Dplot=DensityPlot[10^8/(x^2+y^2),{x,0.01,1},{y,1,5},PlotRange->All,ColorFunction->Automatic,Frame->{True,True,True,True},FrameLabel->{Style["\[Zeta]",20,Bold,Black],Style["\[Kappa]",20,Bold,Black]},FrameTicksStyle->{{Directive[Black,20],Directive[FontOpacity->0,FontSize->0]},{Directive[Black,20],Directive[FontOpacity->0,FontSize->0]}},PlotLegends->BarLegend[{Automatic,{MinV,MaxV}} , LegendMarkerSize->{20,250},LabelStyle->{FontSize->20,Black},Ticks->ForTicks(*,LegendFunction->f*),LegendLabel->"x 10^6"]];

Cplot=ContourPlot[10^8/(x^2+y^2),{x,0.01,1},{y,1,5},ContourShading->None,ContourLabels->(Style[Text[ToString[N[#3/10^Floor[Log[10, #3]]]]<>"E"<>ToString[Floor[Log[10,#3]]],{#1,#2},Background->RGBColor[255/255,255/255,255/255,0.5]],14,RGBColor[0.1,0.2,0.2]]&),ContourStyle->{Dashed},Contours->ChosenTicksC,BaseStyle->18];

Show[Dplot,Cplot]


